# PHP: Splice-like multiple index array removal/extract

Tags: php

Is there a **native** function to remove multiple indexes from an array and then return source array without removed objects or vice versa, to keep only required **indexes** while removing the rest.

Example:

```
$source = array('index1' => 1, 'index2' => 2, 'index3' => 3, 'index4' => 4);
json_encode( array_extract( $source, array('index2','index4'))); // returns array('index2' => 2, 'index4' => 4);
```

or:

```
json_encode( array_except( $source, array('index1','index4'))); // returns array('index2' => 2, 'index3' => 3);
```

Comment: Guess i'll have to write my own helper then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because there is a small problem, your first array contains keys and your second array contains values. There is no function to achieve what you want.

There are multiple functions, array_intersect, array_diff, array_intersect_key, array_diff_key..but they all require matching arrays.